# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.media.projection.MediaProjectionManager

Tags: android

```
MediaProjectionManager manager =
        (MediaProjectionManager) activity.getSystemService(MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = manager.createScreenCaptureIntent();
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_SCREEN_CAPTURE);
```

this is my code and i am getting the following error

```
03-22 07:52:02.271 14831-14831/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.projection.MediaProjectionManager', referenced from method com.zennaxx.marshmallowscreenrecorder.CaptureHelper.fireScreenCaptureIntent
03-22 07:52:02.371 14831-14831/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-22 07:52:02.371 14831-14831/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.zennaxx.marshmallowscreenrecorder, PID: 14831
03-22 07:52:02.371 14831-14831/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.media.projection.MediaProjectionManager
03-22 07:52:02.371 14831-14831/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.zennaxx.marshmallowscreenrecorder.CaptureHelper.fireScreenCaptureIntent(CaptureHelper.java:22)
03-22 07:52:02.371 14831-14831/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.zennaxx.marshmallowscreenrecorder.ScreenRecorderActivity.onLaunchClicked(ScreenRecorderActivity.java:136)
03-22 07:52:02.371 14831-14831/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.zennaxx.marshmallowscreenrecorder.ScreenRecorderActivity$$ViewBinder$6.doClick(ScreenRecorderActivity$$ViewBinder.java:80)
03-22 07:52:02.371 14831-14831/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at butterknife.internal.DebouncingOnClickListener.onClick(DebouncingOnClickListener.java:22)
03-22 07:52:02.371 14831-14831/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4569)
03-22 07:52:02.371 14831-14831/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18570)
03-22 07:52:02.371 14831-14831/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-22 07:52:02.371 14831-14831/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-22 07:52:02.371 14831-14831/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
03-22 07:52:02.371 14831-14831/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
03-22 07:52:02.371 14831-14831/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 07:52:02.371 14831-14831/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-22 07:52:02.371 14831-14831/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
03-22 07:52:02.371 14831-14831/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
03-22 07:52:02.371 14831-14831/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: i am using android studio 1.4 please if any one can help me thank in advance

Answer (score 3):

This exception is typical (i.e. common programming mistake), if you start the app on a device with an API level that is too low. The class needs API Level 21, so you should set min API Level to 21 in your build.gradle or do some exception handling / branching

Comment: thank for response but still it's not working. i got same problem.this problem occurred only in sony mobile android version is 4.4.4 else mobile work properly like in marshmallow android os

Comment: Well, of course it won't work with 4.4.4, since it is API level 19, Marshmallow is 23. This may come in handy in the future: [Android Codenames](https://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html)